# Unable to align icons centrally inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with a simple thing of centrally aligning images inside their table cells. The CSS Margin: auto does not work on Payment Icon and Bonus Offered Icon for some reason. Can you please let me know what is the issue with margin: auto? Thanks.

```
        <table class="payment-table">
            <tr class="payment-table-row payment-table-header">
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Payment System</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Limits</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Commission (%)</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Processing Time</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Bonus Offered</th>
            </tr>   

            <tr class="payment-table-row">
                <td><img src="ico/neteller.png" class="payment-icon"></td>
                <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
                <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % +  £ 1.55</td>
                <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
                <td><img src="ico/yes.png" class="bonus-offered-icon"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="payment-table-row">
                <td><img src="ico/neteller.png" class="payment-icon"></td>
                <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
                <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % + £ 1.55</td>
                <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
                <td><img src="ico/yes.png" class="bonus-offered-icon"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.payment-table{
    width: 60%;
}

.payment-icon{
    margin: auto;
    width: 40px;
}

.bonus-offered-icon{
    width: 20px;
    margin:auto;
}

.table-data{
    max-width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need?

you don't have to use `margin:auto;` to make in center align. you just need to use `text-align:center;` in `td`.

```css
.payment-table {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.payment-table-header-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.payment-table-row td {
  width:15%; /* customize the width of the td if you need */
  border: 1px solid teal;
  text-align: center; /* this is what you need to align center */
}

.payment-icon {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
}

.bonus-offered-icon {
  width: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.table-data {
  max-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="payment-table">
  <tr class="payment-table-row payment-table-header">
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Payment System</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Limits</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Commission (%)</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Processing Time</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Bonus Offered</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="payment-table-row">
    <td><img src="ico/neteller.png" class="payment-icon"></td>
    <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
    <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % + £ 1.55</td>
    <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
    <td><img src="ico/yes.png" class="bonus-offered-icon"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="payment-table-row">
    <td><img src="ico/neteller.png" class="payment-icon"></td>
    <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
    <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % + £ 1.55</td>
    <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
    <td><img src="ico/yes.png" class="bonus-offered-icon"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can further go ahead and make it clean as below:

```css
.payment-table {
  width: 60%; /* customize the width of the whole table */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.payment-table-header-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.payment-table-row td {
  width:15%; /* customize the width of the td if you need */
  border: 1px solid teal;
  text-align: center; /* this is what you need to align center */
}
```

```html
<table class="payment-table">
  <tr class="payment-table-row payment-table-header">
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Payment System</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Limits</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Commission (%)</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Processing Time</th>
    <th class="payment-table-header-item">Bonus Offered</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="payment-table-row">
    <td><img src="ico/neteller.png" class="payment-icon"></td>
    <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
    <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % + £ 1.55</td>
    <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
    <td><img src="ico/yes.png" class="bonus-offered-icon"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="payment-table-row">
    <td><img src="ico/neteller.png" class="payment-icon"></td>
    <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
    <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % + £ 1.55</td>
    <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
    <td><img src="ico/yes.png" class="bonus-offered-icon"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto` is confusing. It does not simply mean "center an element". It behaves differently for different elements. An `<img>` is a `replaced element` or according to the CSS Standard:

> An element whose content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model, such as an image, embedded document, or applet

The behavior of `margin: auto` for `replaced elements` is defined in the CSS Level 2 Standard as:

> The 'width' property does not apply. A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a used value of '0'.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins

Therefore, setting `margin: auto` effectively does nothing.

To achieve the desired result wrap the `<img>` in a non-replaced element such as a `<div>` and set its `margin` and `width`.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.payment-table{
    width: 60%;
}

.payment-icon{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40px;
}

.bonus-offered-icon{
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.table-data{
    max-width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table class="payment-table">
            <tr class="payment-table-row payment-table-header">
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Payment System</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Limits</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Commission (%)</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Processing Time</th>
                <th class="payment-table-header-item">Bonus Offered</th>
            </tr>   

            <tr class="payment-table-row">
                <td><div class="payment-icon"><img src="ico/neteller.png"></div></td>
                <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
                <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % +  £ 1.55</td>
                <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
                <td><div class="bonus-offered-icon"><img src="ico/yes.png"></div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="payment-table-row">
                <td><div class="payment-icon"><img src="ico/neteller.png"></div></td>
                <td class="deposit-limits table-data">£10 - £ 2000</td>
                <td class="deposit-commission table-data">3 % + £ 1.55</td>
                <td class="deposit-processing table-data">Up to 3 Bank Days</td>
                <td><div class="bonus-offered-icon"><img src="ico/yes.png"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
```